# Wrong NumPy array calculations results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.6, calculus

I am stuck trying to figure out why it dosnt work. Must say I am new in python. 
Trying calculate when a^d + b^d = c^d; (Fermat`s theorem) using np.arrays
for best performance.
Problem: wrong results in array B for d > 2.
Please point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Kubuntu 17.10
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

This is code example when problem shows:

```
import numpy as np

d = np.float64(4.)
A = np.float64([[99001457116.0, 99536254152.0],
                [99002341176.0, 99914925909.0],
                [99029463918.0, 99750866948.0]])

B = np.float64((np.sum(A**2, axis=1)**(1/d)).reshape((A.shape[0], 1)))
B
```

Comment: Doesn't Fermat's Last Theorem say that for all integers n > 2, there are no integer solutions to a^n + b^n = c^n? (Not 1/n)

Comment: Yes, it is. But, in B array I trying get "c" (not c^n)

Comment: Why are you using exponents of 2 and 1/4? Those don't match.